# Argument assetDetailController is not a function got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am relatively new in Angular.js so I tried every other solution but it always throws an error assetDetailController is not a function got undefined.. Any advice I tried all the possible solution for this question on this site..

```
 describe('asset detail Controller',
        function () {
            describe('assetDetailController',
                function () {
                    var scope;
                    var rportService;
                    var controller;
                    var $q;
                    var deferred, assetId, rootScope;
                    var httpMock, data;

                    beforeEach(module('app'));

                    // inject the required services and instantiate the controller
                    //beforeEach();

                    describe('asset detail Controller 2',
                        function () {
                            deferred = null;

                            //beforeEach();

                            //beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($q) {

                            //}));

                            beforeEach();

                            it('test to be called with',
                                function ( done) {
                                    angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, reportService, $q, $httpBackend) {
                                        scope = $rootScope.$new();
                                        rportService = reportService;
                                        controller = $controller('assetDetailController',
                                        {
                                            $scope: scope,
                                            assetId: assetId,
                                            reportService: rportService,
                                            rootScope: $rootScope
                                        });
```

Comment: I did not add the remaining linesI thought there should be issue with this part of the code.. so